# Как сохранить результат запроса в переменную для того, что использовать дальше?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Не подскажите, как вот этот запрос к базе:

```
using (var entities = new Entities(PosConnectionString))
{
    var InfoCash = entities.GM_FinActStock
        .Where(terminal => terminal.TerminalID == TerminalId && terminal.BudgetArticle == 5637151398)
        .Select(cashnumber =>
            new {
                cashnumber = cashnumber.Amount
            })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Сохранить в переменную, чтобы потом использовать её дальше в коде?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как вынести объявление этой переменной за блок using?

Comment: int InfoCach; using(...){InfoCash = ...}

Comment: Если без var в using то ругается на другие ошибки

Comment: Так все-таки вы хотите сохранить сам запрос или результат запроса?

Comment: Результат запроса, что бы к нему обратиться дальше в коде

Comment: Прощу прощения, за глупый вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная имеет область видимости. Грубо говоря, она ограничена фигурными скобками, в которых находится эта переменная. То есть, `InfoCash` видна только внутри блока `using`.

Чтобы она была доступна после этого блока, нужно объявить её вне этого блока (перед ним):

```
? InfoCash;

using (var entities = new Entities(PosConnectionString))
{
    InfoCash = ...
}

// здесь InfoCash доступна
```

Знаком вопроса обозначен тип переменной. Какой тип задать? Тот, который возвращает ваш запрос. А именно, тип возвращаемый последним методом `FirstOrDefault`.

В вашем случае возвращается анонимный тип, который создан так: `new { ... }`. Создать переменную анонимного типа можно только с помощью ключевого слова `var` прямо по месту. В другом месте её объявить нельзя. Поэтому нужно избавиться от анонимного типа.

Создадим класс, который будет содержать нужную нам информацию:

```
class InfoCash
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Используем его в запросе:

```
InfoCash infoCash;

using (var entities = new Entities(PosConnectionString))
{
    infoCash = entities.GM_FinActStock
        .Where(terminal => terminal.TerminalID == TerminalId && terminal.BudgetArticle == 5637151398)
        .Select(cashnumber =>
            new InfoCash
            {
                Amount = cashnumber.Amount
            })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

// здесь можно использовать infoCash
```

Однако, дополнительный класс нужен лишь в том случае, если возвращается несколько полей (колонок). А у вас всего одно поле. Поэтому достаточно переменной простого типа.

```
decimal amount;

using (var entities = new Entities(PosConnectionString))
{
    amount = entities.GM_FinActStock
        .Where(terminal => terminal.TerminalID == TerminalId && terminal.BudgetArticle == 5637151398)
        .Select(cashnumber => cashnumber.Amount)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Судя по названию `Amount` - это некая сумма, наверняка деньги. Если это действительно так, то тип должен быть `decimal`. Если у вас `double/float` - исправьте.

---

Запрос можно сократить до следующего:

```
amount = entities.GM_FinActStock
    .FirstOrDefault(terminal => terminal.TerminalID == TerminalId && terminal.BudgetArticle == 5637151398)
    .Amount;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли, разобраться в вопросе. Для себя понял, что нужно по больше теории почитать) Ёще раз спасибо!

Comment: Вместо дополнительного класса можно использовать кортеж же...

Comment: @PavelMayorov - можно, но у автора EntityFramework без указания версии. И объяснять ещё и про туплы, и как их правильно создавать... А ответ и так получился длинным.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а при чём тут версия EntityFramework? Как будто кортежи от неё зависят, а не от версии компилятора...

Comment: @PavelMayorov - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33545601/5045688 - одни версии принимают `Tuple.Create`, другие только `new Tuple`. Плюс `ValueTuple`. Если уж описывать, то сразу все. А лень...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хм, странно, мне почему-то казалось, что там нет ограничения на конструкторы...